swprintf removed from newlib-nano since gcc13
I came across this issue while working on updating our toolchain which uses newlib-nano. The new toolchain version i use is arm-gnu-toolchain-13.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.
When i use arm-none-eabi-nm to analyze the symbols from libc_nano.a there is not the one expected for swprintf. This seems to be the case only since gcc13.
I guess i could add a file which implement this function since we want to keep nano but I thought it would be interesting to talk about it.
Do you guys have an idea of why that is ?
